# *** glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

My following program complies fine but I get the error

> *** glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer

when I run it.

I have this class where everything is declared in a header file.

```
class ErrorState {
    char* eMessage;
public:
    explicit ErrorState(const char* = nullptr);
    ErrorState(const ErrorState&) = delete;
    ErrorState& operator=(const ErrorState&) = delete;
    virtual ~ErrorState();
    void clear();
    bool isClear() const;
    void message(const char*);
    const char* message() const;
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, ErrorState&);
```

And my definitions are in this .cpp file

```
ErrorState::ErrorState(const char* errorMessage) {
    if (errorMessage == nullptr) {
        eMessage = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        message(errorMessage);
    }
}

ErrorState::~ErrorState() {
    clear();
}

void ErrorState::clear() {
    if (eMessage != nullptr) {
        delete[] eMessage;
        eMessage = nullptr;
    }
}

bool ErrorState::isClear() const {
    return (eMessage == nullptr);
}

void ErrorState::message(const char* str) {
    int strLen = strlen(str);
    clear();
    eMessage = new char[strLen + 1];
    strcpy(eMessage, str);
}

const char* ErrorState::message() const {
    return eMessage;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ErrorState& errState) {
    if (!errState.isClear())
        os << errState.message();
    return os;
}
```

I've looked through other solutions but couldn't find anything that works. It'd be appreciated if someone can help.

Ok the problem is with

```
delete[] eMessage;
```

In the clear function. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Why are you using `char[]` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: @Barmar Professor wants it that way.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is happening in the `ErrorState` class? All the point use looks clean to me. Run your program under a debugger and see where it gets the error.

Comment: If you compile with `-g` and then run through `valgrind`, it should tell you which lines of your code are the source of memory errors.

Comment: @Bot: Be aware that the Professor is teaching outdated practices. In fact, he would be on my automatic don-not-hire list for teaching this. Your code above on the other hand has only minor style issues. The error is in code we don't see.

Answer (score 0):

your clear function is behaving like a destructor.

your bug is that clear is called from message(), destructing the message while it is being constructed.

Just remove clear() from message()